# Groovy: Using "in" operator for a list with a regexp inside

Tags: regex, groovy

Is there any way to use the "in" operator for a list with a regexp inside?

```
List myList = ["abc", "xyz", ~/a.+z/]

assert ("abc" in myList) == true
assert ("xyz" in myList) == true

assert ("abz" in myList) == true
assert ("aby" in myList) == false
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to get this to work with `in`.  The best I can think of is to write a custom method, and running that instead like so:

```
boolean isIn( List domain, String target ) {
  domain.find { target ==~ it }
}

List myList = ["abc", "xyz", ~/a.+z/]

assert ( isIn( myList, "abc" ) ) == true
assert ( isIn( myList, "xyz" ) ) == true
assert ( isIn( myList, "abz" ) ) == true
assert ( isIn( myList, "aby" ) ) == false
```

---

Actually, this is possible, but you'll need to either write your own `List` class:

```
class MyList extends ArrayList {
  boolean isCase( Object o ) {
    find { o ==~ it }
  }
}

def myList = new MyList()
myList.addAll( ["abc", "xyz", ~/a.+z/] )

assert ("abc" in myList) == true
assert ("xyz" in myList) == true

assert ("abz" in myList) == true
assert ("aby" in myList) == false
```

Or, overwrite the `isCase` method on the instance meta class for your list:

```
def myList = ["abc", "xyz", ~/a.+z/]
myList.metaClass.isCase = { o ->
  ( delegate.find { o ==~ it } ) as boolean
}
// asserts as before
```

Comment: Too bad. Just as I thought. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @T.Dabrowski Sorry, I was prematurely negative ;-)

Comment: @T.Dabrowski btw, if [epidemian's answer to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8927935/6509) was correct, you could do with [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/156393)